# Как в Woocommerce вывести только те продукты, что есть в наличии с помощью wp_query?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wp-query

У меня есть сайт на wordpress + woocommerce.

На [www.goosto.co.il/?show_slider](https://www.goosto.co.il/?show_slider) нужно вывести товары в слайдере, но только те, что есть в наличии.

Вот фрагмент кода темплейта страницы.

Буду признателен за помощь. Уже много всего перепробовал.

```html
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key' => 'stock_status',
        'value' => 'instock'
    ),
);

$products = new WP_Query($args);

?>

<?php if($products->have_posts()){ ?>
    <div class="test-products">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="add-to-cart-clone-parent catalog">
                <div class="owl-carousel main-products-slider slider-style1 arr-st2 catalog">
                    <?php while ($products->have_posts()) : $products->the_post(); ?>
                        <?php require('inc/parts/category_product.php'); ?>
                    <?php
                    endwhile;
                    wp_reset_query();
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Там для `instock`, мета ключ вроде должен быть `_stock_status`. Ну и к вопросу не относится, но вместо `wp_reset_query();` должно быть `wp_reset_postdata();`. Ну и вместо `require()` обычно используется `get_template_part()`.

Comment: Да, это действительно сработало. Остальные замечания тоже учел. Спасибо.